# Issuu - PDF - Duplicated Content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content, googlebot, pdf

I often write newsletters and publish them on my own site as PDF's.

To potentially drive more traffic to my site, I was thinking about publishing the same newsletter files through sites like Scribd or Issuu.

But would this be considered as duplicated content ??

Comment: Short answer. Yes. But I am sure there are things you can do. I will leave that to someone who may have an idea of what to do or what the good options are.

Answer (score 1):

You might be one step ahead of google bots at this point in time since they primarily scan human readable text on web pages to assess duplicate content, but I highly would suggest not to make multiple copies of the same content as PDFs.

Also, publishing copies of the PDF does not necessarily mean more people will visit your site since they have other web sites they can access to download the PDF from.

Why not just write unique newsletters as HTML documents on your site and create a sitemap that lists the URL to each newsletter and submit it to google via webmaster tools?

Requiring a download of a PDF just to view text is sometimes a pain depending on your visitors. 
Additionally, some users might not have a PDF reader installed. Some older phones that access the internet might not have sufficient technology to even install a PDF reader.

Comment: Many thanks Mike, really appreciate your time and help. I hear your points. If I publish the newsletters in regular html on my site as primary as you suggested and then create a pdf out of it and submit it to Issuu or Scribd, would that be considered as duplicated content ?

Comment: If the text in both versions are exactly the same, then yes it would be duplicate content according to people.

Comment: a) PDF's are indexable by search engine crawlers and b) PDF's don't have to be downloaded to be read, they can be viewed in browser.

Comment: a work around is to publish your newsletters as images on such sites. They won't be readable by machines, thus avoiding duplication.

Comment: zigojacko, All objects (examples: images, flash PDFs, etc) a browser requires in order to display a web page or web content are fetched from the server at least once per user per browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [official blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pdfs-in-google-search-results.html) from Google.

So do not pulibsh your same PDF files on other website, if they also index same PDF on google SERP.

It's good to share your heading and short description of your article on Digg, Reddit, StumbleUpon etc to get some traffic. Don't share your whole article anywhere.